# How do I instantiate a prefab through a script in Unity C# correctly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, dynamic, uibutton

I am instantiating a prefab thru a script in Unity. It's kind of working but not really.
The prefab shows up in the hierarchy with the correct name but in the scene, it cannot be seen.
I have looked through every question I saw, that was similar but unfortunately, I couldn't solve my problem. I tried changing the Vector in the script and the position of the prefab itself.
I appreciate any help.

```cs
public class ButtonControler : MonoBehaviour

[SerializeField] private Button[] buttonsList;
public GameObject button;

public void Awake()
{
   InitializeButtons();
}

private void InitializeButtons()
{
for (int i = 0; i < CsvManagerDownloader.experiments.Count; i++)
{
    string buttontext = "Experiment" + i;
    
    GameObject newButton = Instantiate(button, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    newButton.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = buttontext;
  
    
}
```

(This script can only be called after **CSVManagerDownloader**, since the number of buttons is gathered from that script.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to instantiate an object that is supposed to be used inside `Canvas` (unity UI system) in the world space.

`Canvas` component on the root object is needed to render all child UI elements like `Button`, `Text`, `Image`, etc.

So, if you want your instantiated object with the `Button` component to be visible, make sure, that you place it in the hierarchy with the `Canvas` component attached to any of its parents.

Also, make sure that the `EventSystem` component is present at the scene to make `Buttons` work.

Comment: How do I place it in the hierarchy as a child of Canvas via Script?

Comment: using `SetParent` method of the `Transform` class. If you have a link to the needed object (within the canvas hierarchy) it will look like `myInstantiatedButton.transform.SetParent(targetParent.transform)` https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html

Comment: got it thank you! another quick question, I set the parent as the content in a scroll view, is there a quick way to make sure that all buttons will be spawned under each other like in a list/ usual scrollview? right now the buttons spawn on top of each other, at the bottom of the scrollview

Comment: don't know if this is simple enough, but you know the index of the spawned button (in case of all buttons have the same height) to be able to calculate position or you can simply increase the next button position right after the previous one was added.